# 0% tax for customer group but normal added in checkout

Tags: cart, tax

I'm trying to set tax rates to 0% for a specific customer group ('business'). I configured all tax rates to apply only for customer group 'private', and set a new tax rate to 0% for group 'business'.

In the product view and the search, products are correctly shown with 0% tax. But after adding a product to the cart, it shows up with regular tax rates.

Do you have any idea of what I might be doing wrong? I disabled the automatic group change based on VAT id..

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you adding the product to the cart while logged in or as a guest? The same question applies to browsing the catalog. If you are logged in, which user group is your customer account associated with?

Answer (score 1):

You might find the solution in the function `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item::setProduct` here it appears to add the customer group to the product before getting the tax class from the product.

```
if ($this->getQuote()) {
    $product->setStoreId($this->getQuote()->getStoreId());
    $product->setCustomerGroupId($this->getQuote()->getCustomerGroupId());
}
$this->setData('product', $product)
    ->setProductId($product->getId())
    ->setProductType($product->getTypeId())
    ->setSku($this->getProduct()->getSku())
    ->setName($product->getName())
    ->setWeight($this->getProduct()->getWeight())
    ->setTaxClassId($product->getTaxClassId())
    ->setBaseCost($product->getCost())
    ->setIsRecurring($product->getIsRecurring());
```

Comment: dont fully get what this means. bug?